# jQuery validate textbox 1 if there is same multiple value inside textbox 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 textbox.

```
<input type="text" id="pcbaSerialNo"/>
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="pcbaSerialNoMask"/>
```

and the js

```
function handlePCBASerialNo(e)
{
    var pcbaSerialNo = $(this).val();
    var pcbaSerialNoMask = $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val();

    if(e.which ==13)
    {
        if(pcbaSerialNo == "")
        {}
        else
        {
            if(jQuery.inArray(pcbaSerialNo, pcbaSerialNoMask) != -1)
            {
                alert("Duplicate scan is not allowed!");
            }
            else
            {
                if(pcbaSerialNoMask == "")
                {
                    $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val(pcbaSerialNo);
                    $('#totalScan').val("1");
                }
                else
                {
                    var totalScan = $('#totalScan').val();

                    $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val(pcbaSerialNo + "," + pcbaSerialNoMask);

                    $('#totalScan').val(parseInt(totalScan) + 1);
                }
            }

            $('#pcbaSerialNo').bind('keypress', handlePCBASerialNo);

            $('#pcbaSerialNo').val("");
        }
    }
}
$('#pcbaSerialNo').keypress(handlePCBASerialNo);
```

The js function will run on enter key in textbox.

When scan on textbox `#pcbaSerialNo`, it will send the value to `#pcbaSerialNoMask`. (Example more than 1 value will be: test1, test2)

Now I need to validate `#pcbaSerialNo` to detect if there is same value.

My question, how to validate that textbox to prevent same value(duplicate)?

```js
function handlePCBASerialNo(e)
{
  var pcbaSerialNo = $(this).val();
  var pcbaSerialNoMask = $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val();

  if(e.which ==13)
  {
    if(pcbaSerialNo == "")
    {}
    else
    {
      if(jQuery.inArray(pcbaSerialNo, pcbaSerialNoMask) != -1)
      {
        alert("Duplicate scan is not allowed!");
      }
      else
      {
        if(pcbaSerialNoMask == "")
        {
          $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val(pcbaSerialNo);
          $('#totalScan').val("1");
        }
        else
        {
          var totalScan = $('#totalScan').val();

          $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val(pcbaSerialNo + "," + pcbaSerialNoMask);

          $('#totalScan').val(parseInt(totalScan) + 1);
        }
      }

      $('#pcbaSerialNo').bind('keypress', handlePCBASerialNo);

      $('#pcbaSerialNo').val("");
    }
  }
}
$('#pcbaSerialNo').keypress(handlePCBASerialNo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pcbaSerialNo"/>
<input type="text" id="pcbaSerialNoMask"/>
```

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below line before checking for existing value. You have to convert the string value to array while using `inArray` function.

```
pcbaSerialNoMask = pcbaSerialNoMask.split(",");
```

```js
function handlePCBASerialNo(e)
{
  var pcbaSerialNo = $(this).val();
  var pcbaSerialNoMask = $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val();

  if(e.which ==13)
  {
    if(pcbaSerialNo == "")
    {}
    else
    {
      pcbaSerialNoMask = pcbaSerialNoMask.split(",");
      if(jQuery.inArray(pcbaSerialNo, pcbaSerialNoMask) != -1)
      {
        alert("Duplicate scan is not allowed!");
      }
      else
      {
        if(pcbaSerialNoMask == "")
        {
          $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val(pcbaSerialNo);
          $('#totalScan').val("1");
        }
        else
        {
          var totalScan = $('#totalScan').val();

          $('#pcbaSerialNoMask').val(pcbaSerialNo + "," + pcbaSerialNoMask);

          $('#totalScan').val(parseInt(totalScan) + 1);
        }
      }

      $('#pcbaSerialNo').bind('keypress', handlePCBASerialNo);

      $('#pcbaSerialNo').val("");
    }
  }
}
$('#pcbaSerialNo').keypress(handlePCBASerialNo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pcbaSerialNo"/>
<input type="text" id="pcbaSerialNoMask"/>
```